# How to parse the inner text in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following `html` content:

```
<div class="myClass">
    <b>Title:</b> New event<br/><b>Content:</b> <a href="some email">Parsing with BeautifulSoup </a> 
(Options goes here)<br/><b>Time:</b> Jan 12 2015 11:20:17
    <br/>
</div>
```

I would like get `Title:`, `Content` and `Time` information as this output:

`New event`

`Parsing with BeautifulSoup`

`Jan 12 2015 11:20:17`

I know I can do it by first taking all the content of `myClass` then parse the string manually . Is it possible to do it directly using BeautifulSoup?

**EDIT:** I can also use `soup.find('div', {'class': 'myClass'}).b.next_sibling` but this would leave `Parsing with BeautifulSoup` out

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out that it can be solved like this:

```
title = soup.find('div', {'class': 'myClass'}).a.text
content = soup.find('div', {'class': 'myClass'}).b.next_sibling
time = soup.find('div', {'class': 'myClass'}).a.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling
```

Any other suggestion is welcome :)